# Is there a reason why classlist.add is not adding the "hide" class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an accordion component, the angle-up element is meant to close the section when you click it but it's not adding the hide class, what's the problem?

The html (icons are from font-awesome)

```
<div class="accordion-items">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <p class="item-header">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
              <i class="angle-down fa fa-angle-down"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-up angle-up hide"></i>
            </p>

            <p class="item-content hide">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor
              quos eum cupiditate nulla quas ea numquam praesentium, molestias
              culpa nemo ab fuga deserunt.
            </p>
            <!-- <hr /> -->
          </div>

          <div class="accordion-item">
            <p class="item-header">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
              <i class="angle-down fa fa-angle-down"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-up angle-up hide"></i>
            </p>

            <p class="item-content hide">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor
              quos eum cupiditate nulla quas ea numquam praesentium, molestias
              culpa nemo ab fuga deserunt.
            </p>
            <!-- <hr /> -->
          </div>

          <div class="accordion-item">
            <p class="item-header">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
              <i class="angle-down fa fa-angle-down"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-up angle-up hide"></i>
            </p>

            <p class="item-content hide">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor
              quos eum cupiditate nulla quas ea numquam praesentium, molestias
              culpa nemo ab fuga deserunt.
            </p>
            <!-- <hr /> -->
          </div>

          <div class="accordion-item">
            <p class="item-header">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
              <i class="angle-down fa fa-angle-down"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-up angle-up hide"></i>
            </p>

            <p class="item-content hide">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor
              quos eum cupiditate nulla quas ea numquam praesentium, molestias
              culpa nemo ab fuga deserunt.
            </p>
            <!-- <hr /> -->
          </div>

          <div class="accordion-item">
            <p class="item-header">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down angle-down"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-up angle-up hide"></i>
            </p>

            <p class="item-content hide">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quasi
              nam dolorem aliquam, placeat, sed dolores provident natus,
              voluptate rem vel numquam. Repellendus.
            </p>
            <!-- <hr /> -->
          </div>
        </div>
```

The css

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.accordion-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Javascript

```
"use strict"

const itemHeaderEls = document.querySelectorAll(".item-header")
const itemContentEls = document.querySelectorAll(".item-content")
const angleDownEls = document.querySelectorAll(".angle-down")
const angleUpEls = document.querySelectorAll(".angle-up")

const openItemContent = (i) => {
  itemHeaderEls[i].classList.add("bold")
  itemContentEls[i].classList.remove("hide")
  angleUpEls[i].classList.remove("hide")
  angleDownEls[i].classList.add("hide")
}

const closeItemContent = (i) => {
  itemHeaderEls[i].classList.remove("bold")
  itemContentEls[i].classList.add("hide")
  angleUpEls[i].classList.add("hide")
  angleDownEls[i].classList.remove("hide")
}

itemHeaderEls.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const itemIndex = Array.from(itemHeaderEls).indexOf(el)
    openItemContent(itemIndex)
  })
})

angleUpEls.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const itemIndex = Array.from(angleUpEls).indexOf(el)
    closeItemContent(itemIndex)
  })
})

angleDownEls.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const testIndex = Array.from(angleDownEls).indexOf(el)
    openItemContent(testIndex)
  })
})
```

When I click the icon i'd like to add the hide class and remove the bold class, why won't it work?

Comment: Hint: instead of using indices to access all other elements on click, use relational information in the DOM, e.g. `e.currentTarget.parent` or the likes. This makes your solution more bulletproof.

Comment: Also, please share a [mcve]. It seems that you're using the font-awesome library and there will be styles that will override your `display: none` property in the your `.hide` class.

Comment: here's the repl: https://replit.com/@MarkOrji/GlamorousCautiousMigration

Comment: Your `.angle-up` element is also a child of `.item-header`, so click on it will trigger BOTH open + close functions. You need to use `e.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the issue is because when you click on the `.angle-up` or `.angle-down` elements, the click event **is bubbling up to the parent** and it causes both the close + open function to be fired at the same time.

The trick is simply to use `e.stopPropagation()` on the click event handlers bound to the child nodes.

See example below:

```js
const itemHeaderEls = document.querySelectorAll(".item-header")
const itemContentEls = document.querySelectorAll(".item-content")
const angleDownEls = document.querySelectorAll(".angle-down")
const angleUpEls = document.querySelectorAll(".angle-up")

const openItemContent = (i) => {
  itemHeaderEls[i].classList.add("bold")
  itemContentEls[i].classList.remove("hide")
  angleUpEls[i].classList.remove("hide")
  angleDownEls[i].classList.add("hide")
}

const closeItemContent = (i) => {
  itemHeaderEls[i].classList.remove("bold")
  itemContentEls[i].classList.add("hide")
  angleUpEls[i].classList.add("hide")
  angleDownEls[i].classList.remove("hide")
}

itemHeaderEls.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const itemIndex = Array.from(itemHeaderEls).indexOf(el)
    openItemContent(itemIndex)
  })
})

angleUpEls.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const itemIndex = Array.from(angleUpEls).indexOf(el)
    closeItemContent(itemIndex)
  })
})

angleDownEls.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const testIndex = Array.from(angleDownEls).indexOf(el)
    openItemContent(testIndex)
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.accordion-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="accordion-items">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <p class="item-header">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
      <i class="angle-down fa fa-angle-down"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up angle-up hide"></i>
    </p>

    <p class="item-content hide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor quos eum cupiditate nulla quas ea numquam praesentium, molestias culpa nemo ab fuga deserunt.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <p class="item-header">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
      <i class="angle-down fa fa-angle-down"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up angle-up hide"></i>
    </p>

    <p class="item-content hide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor quos eum cupiditate nulla quas ea numquam praesentium, molestias culpa nemo ab fuga deserunt.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <p class="item-header">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
      <i class="angle-down fa fa-angle-down"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up angle-up hide"></i>
    </p>

    <p class="item-content hide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor quos eum cupiditate nulla quas ea numquam praesentium, molestias culpa nemo ab fuga deserunt.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <p class="item-header">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
      <i class="angle-down fa fa-angle-down"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up angle-up hide"></i>
    </p>

    <p class="item-content hide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor quos eum cupiditate nulla quas ea numquam praesentium, molestias culpa nemo ab fuga deserunt.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <p class="item-header">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down angle-down"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up angle-up hide"></i>
    </p>

    <p class="item-content hide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quasi nam dolorem aliquam, placeat, sed dolores provident natus, voluptate rem vel numquam. Repellendus.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```